# Pointer to string constants

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

according to the definition

```
char *str = "ankit"
```

here `str` is a pointer to char.

when we do something like

```
cout<< str;
```

then it is printing ankit. why not the address where ankit is stored, as `str` is a pointer so it must be a address

I have tried to print `*str` which comes out to be "a"; which I can understand but I am unable to understand why printing str is not giving pointer but the string value.

```
char * str = "ankit";
cout<< str;
```

output : ankit

Comment: See what happens if you do `cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(str);`. Also see [Why does my pointer output a string and not a memory address in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7788639/608639) and [cout << with char* argument prints string, not pointer value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17813423/608639).

Comment: Smurf. I should have realized this was answered and answered again.

Comment: Interesting side note: `char * str = "ankit";` is illegal according to the C++11 Standard and subsequent C++ Standards. String literals are constant arrays of characters and you are not allowed to use a non-constant pointer to point at constant data in order to prevent accidents where the constant data is written to.

Answer (score 1):

ostream has different overloads for `char *` and `T *` (for a template type `T`).

From the `<ostream>` header file:

```
template <class _Traits>
inline basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
    const char* _Val) { // insert NTBS into char stream
```

```
template <class _Ostr, class _Ty,
    enable_if_t<conjunction_v< // prevent infinite recursion
                    negation<is_lvalue_reference<_Ostr>>, is_base_of<ios_base, _Ostr>, _Can_stream_out<_Ostr, _Ty>>,
        int> = 0>
inline _Ostr&& operator<<(_Ostr&& _Os, const _Ty& _Val) { // insert to rvalue stream
```

The function accepting `char *` parameters would be used if a known C string is given.

If it is not available, the other function that accepts arbitrary pointer values would be used.

There is also a method that accepts a `void *` pointer.